# Capturing failures when writing to BigQuery in Dataflow pipeline

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a Dataflow pipeline reading event data from a PubSub topic. When receiving a message, i do a transformation step, to fit the event data to my desired BigQuery schema. However, if my created input does not fit the schema, I run into problems. Apparently it is infinitely retried to write to BigQuery:

```
Count: 76   RuntimeError: Could not successfully insert rows to BigQuery table
```

Currently I am doing a lot of manual checking that the input does fit the schema, however, in cases I did not consider, i get accumulating RuntimeErrors. Is there a way to try writing to BigQuery and in case this fails doing something else with the original input? Alternatively, is there a way to try writing a number of times, and otherwise silently fail without adding new RuntimeErrors?

**Edit:** I am using the python SDK. Here is my simplified pipeline for further clarification:

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as pipeline:
    # Read messages from PubSub
    event = (pipeline
             | 'Read from PubSub' >> beam.io.gcp.pubsub.ReadStringsFromPubSub(topic))

    output = (event
              | 'Create output' >> beam.transforms.core.FlatMap(lambda event: [{'input': event}]))

    # Write to Big Query
    _ = (output
         | 'Write log to BigQuery' >> beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery(
             table=table,
             dataset=dataset,
             project=project,
             schema=schema,
             create_disposition=beam.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_NEVER,
             write_disposition=beam.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND))
```

If there is no column 'input' in my table, the job dies. After looking in https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py#L1279 it seems, this is the reason for this behaviour. By customizing https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py#L1187 and not raising the RuntimeError, I can overcome my problem, however, this feels quite cumbersome. Does someone have a suggestion for an easier way?

Comment: Did you run one of the template dataflow pipelines to do this? Is there any more information for that error?

Comment: I created a custom dataflow pipeline in python. For payloads that fit the schema, the job runs fine. Custom validation filters a list a problems, which get written to a separate debug table, which also works fine. However, in cases I did not consider, the job dies. I edited the question with a simplified pipeline to give more details.

Comment: A public feature request related to your situation is open. You can follow it here - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110334821

Comment: Oh great, i really appreciate this!

Answer (score 1):

Something that may help you (when using the direct runner) is getting the ['FailedRows'] from the insertion to

```
 final_to_bq = (data
                   | 'Write to BQ' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery( ... )
)
```

Then:

```
print_failed_rows = (final_to_bq['FailedRows']
                         | 'print failed' >> beam.ParDo(Printer())
                         )
```

That is helpful using the *DirectRunner* ... but not working with the *DatflowRunner* yet...

Answer (score 0):

If you wrote the pipeline itself you should be able to use [setFailedInsertRetryPolicy](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/cd92c5e2edd275c377793532ac65b07fb571590d/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.java#L1155) on BigQueryIO to  [InsertRetryPolicy.neverRetry](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/53c9bf4cd325035fabde192c63652ef6d591b93c/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/InsertRetryPolicy.java#L51)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. However, I am using python, and could not find something similar. I edited the question to give more details

Comment: Ahh, python doesn't have an equivalent feature yet. But I understand your need of wanting your pipeline to keep moving, even if an element fails.

Answer (score -1):

The Beam - Python SDK for streaming is quite limited.

https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-streaming/

> Python streaming pipeline execution is experimentally available (with some limitations) starting with Beam SDK version 2.5.0.

Python streaming execution does not currently support the following features.

**General Beam features**:
These unsupported Beam features apply to all runners.

- State and Timers APIs
- Custom source API
- Splittable DoFn API
- Handling of late data
- User-defined custom WindowFn

**DataflowRunner specific features**:
Additionally, DataflowRunner does not currently support the following Cloud Dataflow specific features with Python streaming execution.

- Streaming autoscaling
- Updating existing pipelines
- Cloud Dataflow Templates
- Some monitoring features, such as msec counters, display data, metrics, and element counts for transforms. However, logging, watermarks, and element counts for sources are supported.

More information here: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-streaming/#unsupported-features

Also check the below release notes in DataFlow docs:
[image: Python Dataflow Streaming limitation]

Comment: Thanks for this, however, I can not see something related to my problem. Additionally, there is something confusing me: It says "Python streaming pipeline execution is experimentally available [...] starting with Beam SDK version 2.5.0." (currently the latest release is 2.4.0) which is in line with the Release notes of the Dataflow SDK for python. However, a pipeline like the one I posted above is working for me in streaming mode with some (for my purposes minor) limitations. Am I missing something?

Comment: The Dataflow python SDK for streaming is available but some of the features might change and some of the features are not working yet. Hence, some of the simple streaming examples might work as that feature might have been developed. I guess the point is that they are going to have most of the features released by 2.5.0.